# How to wrap a span around the ‘PM’ and ‘AM’ in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, time

I want to wrap a span around the AM or PM in a time string. For example:

```
<span class="time">between 10:00AM and 14:00PM</span>
```

becomes:

```
<span class="time">between 10:00<span class="suffix am">AM</span> and 14:00<span class="suffix pm">PM</span></span>
```

Any clue on how to get the replace method to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a simple replace() would do it:

```
$('.time').each(function() {
  var newMarkup = $(this).html().replace(/AM/g, '<span class="suffix am">AM</span>')
                                .replace(/PM/g, '<span class="suffix pm">PM</span>');

  $(this).html(newMarkup);
});
```

Inspired by: [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string-javascript)

Comment: Alternatively, you can add the spans with 'suffix' class beforehand, and then test for AM/PM existence in the markup and call jQuery's addClass('am') or addClass('pm') on the span.

Comment: @Marcel, I'm pretty that IS a regex. :)

Comment: Uhm, yes, you're right. :) But `.replace('AM', '<span class="suffix am">AM</span>', 'g')` doesn't use a regex, which is rather costly (but perhaps the JavaScript engine does internally use one).

Comment: it IS a regex! at least the /AM/g part. if you wanted to make it case insensitive you could add an i. for example /AM/gi would make it match AM or am.

Comment: Regarding the costly comment, I wouldn't totally disagree - that's why I provided an alternative idea that only applies CSS classes, instead of manipulating the DOM.

Comment: Can manipulate the DOM though any other means that JS, no access to HTML, so this answer is the right one as is.

Answer (score 2):

Could you capitalize the `am`/`pm` class names? In that case this would be a solution:

```
$('.time').html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/(AM|PM)/g, '<span class="suffix $1">$1</span>');
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pVWh6/