# replace all occurrences in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

How can you replace all occurrences found in a string?

If you want to replace all the newline characters (\n) in a string..

This will only replace the first occurrence of newline

```
str.replace(/\\n/, '<br />');
```

I cant figure out how to do the trick?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use the global flag.

```
str.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example.3a_Using_global_and_ignore_with_replace   "Non-standard A string specifying a combination of regular expression flags. The use of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is non-standard. Instead of using this parameter, use a RegExp object with the corresponding flags."

Comment: What's your point? My solution doesn't use the non-standard flags parameter.

Comment: I don't think this is a universal solution as your function seems to be incapable, of replacing "|"s with "~~" or something like that
`var text= "|ABC|DEF||XYZ|||";
text = replaceAllSubString(text, '|', '~~');
alert(text);`

and a function defN :

`function replaceAllSubString(targetString, subString, replaceWith) {
  while (targetString.indexOf(subString) != -1) {
   targetString = targetString.replace(subString, replaceWith);
  }
  return targetString;
 }`

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ivenay/1/)

Comment: `|` is a special character in regular expressions, so you must escape it: `text = text.replace(/\|/g, '~~')`

Comment: I had a hard time with using this answer since my string had a bunch of special regex characters, I used jsbins solution and it works great and it is obvious.  Note I couldn't get Matt's code to work(below).

Answer (score 41):

Brighams answer uses `literal regexp`.

Solution with a Regex object.

```
var regex = new RegExp('\n', 'g');
text = text.replace(regex, '<br />');
```

TRY IT HERE : [JSFiddle Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/YP3KW/)

Comment: Uh, the *parameter* is non-standard. Using the flag directly after the expression is fine. You're essentially doing the same thing as the other answer except using the RegExp constructor (which is commonly used for dynamic expressions).

Comment: @Matt Says who? There is reference from Mozilla in my post. Where is your reference?

Comment: You're misreading the source. `//` is the literal form of a RegExp object. MDC states the third (not the first) parameter is non-standard.

Comment: /\\n/ is a regex, '\\n' would be a string.

Comment: The very first example in your link uses flags on a regex literal, as in my answer.

Comment: @Matt @Brigham yeah you are right. In this case literal usage seems to be okay. String.replace has some different implementations so i am always using regexp form to avoid incompatibility.

Comment: Your sample does nothing - had it worked, you would have seen 2 `<br />`s in one line instead of three lines. You shouldn't include the delimiters  in the string `"/\\n/"` should be simply `"\n"`. You don't *have to* escape the backslash either, but that one will work either way.

Comment: This is a great answer, it also works with simple unicode matching like removing bom character using `new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(65279), 'g')`

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](http://arta86.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/replace-karakter-pada-string-javascript/), you can use:

```
function replaceall(str,replace,with_this)
{
    var str_hasil ="";
    var temp;

    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) // not need to be equal. it causes the last change: undefined..
    {
        if (str[i] == replace)
        {
            temp = with_this;
        }
        else
        {
                temp = str[i];
        }

        str_hasil += temp;
    }

    return str_hasil;
}
```

... which you can then call using:

```
var str = "50.000.000";
alert(replaceall(str,'.',''));
```

The function will alert "50000000"