# Display json Object Data into Drop down list angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5

HTML

```html
              <!-- level One  Offer for Drop Down -->
              <div class="row no-overflow">
                <div class="col-md-1 window-pad-height no-overflow">
                  <mat-label> Level 1: </mat-label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
                  <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
                    <mat-select placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOfferOne">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="" [value]="levelone">
                        

                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- level Two  Offer for Drop Down -->
              <div class="row no-overflow">
                <div class="col-md-1  no-overflow">
                  <mat-label> Level 2: </mat-label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
                  <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
                    <mat-select placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOfferTwo">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="" [value]="leveltwo">
                        
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- level Three Offer for Drop Down -->
              <div class="row no-overflow">
                <div class="col-md-1 no-overflow">
                  <mat-label> Level 3: </mat-label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
                  <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
                    <mat-select placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOfferThree">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="" [value]="levelthree">
                        
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
              </div>


              <!-- level Four Offer for Drop Down -->
              <div class="row no-overflow">
                <div class="col-md-1 no-overflow">
                  <mat-label> Level 4: </mat-label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
                  <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
                    <mat-select placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOfferFour">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="" [value]="levelfour">
                        
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- level Five Offer for Drop Down -->
              <div class="row no-overflow">
                <div class="col-md-1 no-overflow">
                  <mat-label> Level 5: </mat-label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
                  <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
                    <mat-select placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOfferFive">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="" [value]="levelfive">
                        
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
              </div>
```

JSON

```
LevelValue: any= 
  {
    "level1": [{
            "level1Name": "Prepaid",
            "level2": [ {
                    "level2Name": "data",
                    "level3": [ {
                            "level3Name": "getCustomer",
                            "level4": [{
                                    "level4Name": "Prepaid",
                                    "level5": [
                                        "1",
                                        "2",
                                        "3"
                                    ]
                                }, {
                                    "level4Name": "Postpaid",
                                    "level5": [
                                        "4",
                                        "5",
                                        "6"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

level1Name should be display in level one drop down

level2Name should be display in level two drop down

level3Name should be display in level three drop down

level4Name should be display in level four drop down
as per the level 4 selection values should get change in level 5 drop down 
this json data is coming from the API 
My StackBlitz Link -- > https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cztf8k

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185837/discussion-between-prashant-pimpale-and-just-teach-me).

Comment: @PrashantPimpale can you check my new Qn?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale how to reset drop down if i select in between values bcz ngModel hold its value!

Comment: `ddlSelected = undefined`?

Comment: yes its working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `LevelValue.level1` in first `*ngFor` and then `[(ngModel)]` property of that in the subsequent `*ngFor`. Also set the `[value]` to `level` for each `mat-option`

Give this a try:

```
<!-- level One  Offer for Drop Down -->
<div class="row no-overflow">
  <div class="col-md-1 window-pad-height no-overflow">
    <mat-label> Level 1: </mat-label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
    <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
      <mat-select placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOfferOne">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let level of LevelValue.level1" [value]="level">
          {{level.level1Name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- level Two  Offer for Drop Down -->
<div class="row no-overflow">
  <div class="col-md-1  no-overflow">
    <mat-label> Level 2: </mat-label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
    <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
      <mat-select placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOfferTwo">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let level of selectedOfferOne.level2" [value]="level">
          {{level.level2Name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- level Three Offer for Drop Down -->
<div class="row no-overflow">
  <div class="col-md-1 no-overflow">
    <mat-label> Level 3: </mat-label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
    <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
      <mat-select placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOfferThree">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let level of selectedOfferTwo.level3" [value]="level">
          {{level.level3Name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- level Four Offer for Drop Down -->
<div class="row no-overflow">
  <div class="col-md-1 no-overflow">
    <mat-label> Level 4: </mat-label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
    <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
      <mat-select placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOfferFour">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let level of selectedOfferThree.level4" [value]="level">
          {{level.level4Name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- level Five Offer for Drop Down -->
<div class="row no-overflow">
  <div class="col-md-1 no-overflow">
    <mat-label> Level 5: </mat-label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 no-overflow">
    <mat-form-field class="no-overflow">
      <mat-select placeholder="select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOfferFive">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let level of selectedOfferFour.level5" [value]="level">
          {{ level }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-level-dropdown-selection-eg?file=app/table-basic-example.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Yes its working ! but this json data coming from API and i stored in this.response how to use this.response in HTML?

Comment: Thanks Its Working

Comment: level 1 to level 2 ngModel contains value in array but i want in ngModel value that should be what i select in ng model

Comment: this is working fine but it contained enter and white spaces that is \t \n !how to resolve

Comment: Just [replace them using String's `replace` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9018110/2622292).

Comment: level1: "Dongle ↵ "
level2: "Lifetime Extension ↵ "
level3: "Loyalty (Increase Satisfaction) ↵ "
level4: "Tariff Perception ↵ "
level5: "Low Value ↵ "  this is my json look like

Comment: how to reset values if i select 1 2 drop down bcoz ng model hold values!