# Replacing \t, \n and white space in JS

Tags: javascript

How to do I go about changing a string from "\n        \t\t\t\t\t\t\tArthur Lynch        \t\t\t\t\t\t" to "Authur Lynch" in javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove tab ('\t') from string javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018015/remove-tab-t-from-string-javascript)

Comment: If it's just whitespace at the beginning and end, use `string.trim()`

Answer (score 0):

try [str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

e.g.

```
str.replace(/\n/g,'').replace(/\r/g,'');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked