# How can I change values inside an array of elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
[<input id=​"unit_quantity_0" name=​"lines[0]​[quantity]​" placeholder=​"Quantité" type=​"text" value=​"23,60">​
,<input id=​"unit_quantity_2" name=​"lines[2]​[quantity]​" placeholder=​"Quantité" type=​"text" value=​"5,60">​]
```

How do I change the '`,`' in values to '`.`'

`$("[id^=unit_quantity_]")` returns the array.

Thanks.

Comment: You have an array of DOM elements. The `<input id=​"unit_quantity_0"....` is just their textual representation in the console. `$("[id^=unit_quantity_]")` does not return an array but a jQuery object. You can use [jQuery methods](http://api.jquery.com/) to manipulate the selected elements (which is the whole point of jQuery). See also: [replace all occurrences in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6064956/218196).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$("[id^='unit_quantity_']").val(function (i, old) {
    return old.replace(/,/g, ".");
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/325We/

Using the overload of [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) that takes a function that lets you describe how to replace the old values.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[id^=unit_quantity_]").each(function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    $this.val( $this.val().replace(/,/g,'.'));
});
```