# Why my Replace isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

I have this

```
<p id="demo">/,\,:,*,?,",<,>,|</p>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Replace"/>

function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var n = str.replace(",", ", ");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

What I want is to replace this `"/,\,:,*,?,",<,>,|"` with this `"/, \, :, *, ?, ", <, >, |"` but what I get is this `"/, \,:,*,?,",<,>,|"`.

What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: You find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064956/replace-all-occurrences-in-a-string

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string -- So obviously a duplicate amoung lots of other topics about the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a regex to replace the string `g`lobally:

```
var n = str.replace(/,/g, ', ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line
`var n = str.replace(",", ", ");`

with

`var n = str.replace(/,/g, ", ");`

Default it only will replace the first occurens

Answer (score -1):

The replace in javascript replaces only the first occurrence.

You need do use either regex, or a loop.

Check this out : [Javascript multiple replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832257/javascript-multiple-replace)