# javascript - replacing spaces with a string

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and need a bit of help with program on a college course to replace all the spaces in a string with the string "spaces".

I've used the following code but I just can't get it to work:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type ="text/javascript">
// Program to replace any spaces in a string of text with the word "spaces".
var str = "Visit Micro soft!";

var result = "";

For (var index = 0; index < str.length ; index = index + 1)
{ 
    if (str.charAt(index)= " ")
    {
        result = result + "space";

    }
    else
    { 
        result = result + (str.charAt(index));

    }

}   

document.write(" The answer is " + result );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you if statement needs a == instead of an =. == is for comparison and = is for saving things inside of variables (assignment)

Comment: In what way does it 'not work'?

Answer (score 5):

```
For
```

isn't capitalized:

```
for
```

and

```
str.charAt(index)= " "
```

needs to be:

```
str.charAt(index) == " "
```

[**JavaScript Comparison Operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

[**for loops**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned there are a few obvious errors in your code:

1. The control flow keyword `for` must be all lower-case.
2. The assignment operator `=` is different than the comparison operators `==` and `===`.

If you are allowed to use library functions then this problem looks like a good fit for the JavaScript [`String.replace(regex,str)` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: hey now. it's clearly an entry level assignment in an entry level class. If he pulls out regex the teacher will be a bit fishy. :p

Comment: @ImportedNoob: true, but I'll bet if you search the internet for "JavaScript string replace" (derived simply from the goal of the homework) you could get yourself to the same place...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/(\s)/g, "spaces")
```

Or take a look at this previous answer to a similar question: [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string-javascript/2116614#2116614)
 Hope this help

Comment: That will only replace the first instance of the space character.

Comment: That will only replace the first space.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to skip the `for` cycle altogether and use a regular expression:

```
"Visit Micro soft!".replace(/(\s)/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the string `replace` method. Inconvenienty, there is no `replaceAll`, but you can replace all anyways using a loop.

Example of replace:

```
var word = "Hello"
word = word.replace('e', 'r')
alert(word) //word = "Hrllo"
```

The second tool that will be useful to you is `indexOf`, which tells you where a string occurs in a string. It returns -1 if the string does not appear.

Example:

```
var sentence = "StackOverflow is helpful"
alert(sentence.indexOf(' ')) //alerts 13
alert(sentence.indexOf('z')) //alerts -1
```