# Regex for creating a new line

Tags: regex

i would like your help to help me create a regex that will replace each "\r\n" syntax to a new line, like this example:

```
POST / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: mywebsite.net\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length:
400\r\nContent-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\nUser-Agent: Apache-
HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_74)\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,def1ate
```

To this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.0
Host: mywebsite.net
Connection: close
Content-Length: 400
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_74)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

many thanks!

Comment: Please provide more details on where you are trying to write your Regex.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: You don't need regex to solve your problem. Just use simple plain-text replacement in whatever language you're using. For example in java: `String formatted = str.replace("\\r\\n", "\n");` or replace with `"\r\n"` as you like

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace '\'n in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072313/replace-n-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that.
I am using java pattern class to evaluate regular expressions. 
It is on a graylog system that collect the access log (request and response) from the server. 
[extractor configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM0BL.jpg)

I was trying to make `\\r\\n` and replace with `\r\n` but it didnt help.