# In Graylog2, is it possible to use an extractor to create a field which gets displayed with newlines?

Tags: graylog2

I am receiving a message in Graylog which is very long, and would like to split it up in an extractor. I can use the "Replace with regular expression" extractor to replace certain tokens with other symbols (including \n, \\n, <br />, etc) but in the /search view the field is always rendered in a single line with those characters escaped.

Is there a way to render a field populated with an extractor as multiple lines in Graylog2? Or is the only way to send the message as multi-line from the source?

Comment: Just found https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server/issues/5225 that suggests it's not possible.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468166/regex-for-creating-a-new-line