# Replace a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I know this is a simple task but I can't seem to find the solution.

I've got a date in the format: 20/02/2013
I just wanna replace the / by -
I've got that so far but it only replaces the first slash... Don't know why not the second:

```
date = 20/02/2013;
date.replace('/', '-');
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a regular expression with [*global* flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags):

```
"20/02/2013".replace(/\//g, "-");   // "20-02-2013"
```

Another way is to use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)/[`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
"20/02/2013".split("/").join("-");  // "20-02-2013"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the global flag.

```
str.replace(/\//g, '-');
```