# String formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string format which can be like

```
"( C1 AND C2 OR C3 AND C4) OR (C5 AND C6 ) OR C7"
```

now there is going to generic string like this and i need to remove any space b/w '(' ')' and the 'C' which is condition
for above example i want it to be changed to

```
"(C1 AND C2 OR C3 AND C4) OR (C5 AND C6) OR C7"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string) SO answer.

Use the replace function from [here](http://dumpsite.com/forum/index.php?topic=4.msg8#msg8)

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(str1, str2, ignore)
{
   return this.replace(new RegExp(str1.replace(/([\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g, function(c){return "\\" + c;}), "g"+(ignore?"i":"")), str2);
};
var str = "( C1 AND C2 OR C3 AND C4) OR (C5 AND C6 ) OR C7";
str.replaceAll("( ", "(").replaceAll(" )", ")");
```

Jack's answer is much better and more succinct though.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "( C1 AND C2 OR C3 AND C4) OR (C5 AND C6 ) OR C7";

str.replace(/(\()\s+|\s+(\))/g, '$1$2')
```