# Remove extra br tags with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, formatting

I have a post which contains extra line breaks and want to limit the post to only show one linebreak. I thought this css might work..

```
br+br{display:none}
```

but since the text is not wrapped in its own element all the line breaks in the post are siblings and this doesn't work... now I am trying to solve this with JS...

```
content.replace(/<br><br>/g,'<br>')
```

Why is this only replacing the first set of linebreaks that are next to each other? (I need to run it multiple times to get the effect I want of **all** uneccesary line breaks being removed)
and what should I do instead?

Comment: You might try: http://dumpsite.com/forum/index.php?topic=4.msg8#msg8 --- taken from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6714233/259014)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your regex represents your HTML *exactly*, this should work:

```
content.replace(/(<br>)+/g,'<br>')
```

Although your CSS should've worked: http://jsfiddle.net/UvVbE/

Comment: Perfect thanks! Used the JS, (the css wasn't working cause my text wasn't wrapped in individual elements and there were trailing line breaks too)