# How do I add prevent my regex from parsing certain parts of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

[As per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6714233/355682), I am making use of a `replaceAll()` function to swap arbitrary strings in my javascript (Node) application:

```
this.replaceAll = function(str1, str2, ignoreCase)
{
    return this.replace(new RegExp(str1.replace(/([\/\,\!\\\^\$\{\}\[\]\(\)\.\*\+\?\|\<\>\-\&])/g,"\\$&"),(ignoreCase?"gi":"g")),(typeof(str2)=="string")?str2.replace(/\$/g,"$$$$"):str2);
}
```

I would like to expand this regex, such that it does **not** try to match anything **inside** a set of `<span>...</span>` tags. (I need to add HTML Span tags around parts of some strings, and I don't want to wrap anything in a span *twice*, if the patterns would duplicate [I.e., 'Foo' and 'Foobar' in the string "Foobarbaz"])

I am running multiple regex search/replaces on a single string, and I want to make sure that nothing gets processed multiple times.

My understanding is that I'll need a `[<SPAN>] ... [</SPAN>]` somehow, but I'm not quite sure on the specifics. Any advice?

Comment: You don't need to escape symbols in character groups.

Comment: You might want to tell us what this... piece of code is supposed to do (input->output).

Comment: @thg435 Ah, fair point. Eseentially, take in some raw text, and put HTML tags (a Span with an ID) around matched patterns. The problem is, I don't want to match things that have already been wrapped in a Span.

Comment: @fardjad Wasn't trying to; I want to avoid the html tags, which have the `/` as part of the text.

Comment: There is a concept of look ahead and lookbehind you may have to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what your regexp does, but in general the technique is like this:

```
html = "replace this and this but not <span> this one </span> or <b>this</b> but this is fine"

// remove parts you don't want to be touched and place them in a buffer
tags = []
html = html.replace(/<(\w+).+?<\/\1>/g, function($0) {
    tags.push($0)
    return '@@' + (tags.length - 1)
})

// do the actual replacement
html = html.replace(/this/g, "that")

// put preserved parts back
html = html.replace(/@@(\d+)/g, function($0, $1) {
    return tags[$1]
})
```

Comment: I see! So you split it up into multiple replace functions. This'll work. Makes sense to me!