# Javascript - Replace more than one value

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a problem with my script. I want to replace all spaces with `+`.

The script works with the first space, e.g. for `Crazy dog`:

```
Crazy+dog
```

But with a third word it does no longer work, e.g. for `Crazy dog cat`:

```
Crazy+dog cat
```

I'm using the following JavaScript code:

```
function search() {
    location.href = 'buscar/'+document.getElementById('appendedInputButton').value.replace(' ','+');
}
```

I searched how to do it, but nothing works me, I have not much experience with JavaScript.

**Edit:**

Sorry for the repost, I tried using the `/ ... /` but it did not work as expected. Now I know, I should be working more with `encodeURI`.

Comment: Try replacing with `/ /g`. Or try `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Looks like you have not searched a lot...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: When working with a URL you should url encode it, not replace characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use regular expression with `g` flag to replace all occurrences.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function search()
    {
        location.href = 'buscar/'+document.getElementById('appendedInputButton').value.replace(/\s+/g, '+');
    }
</script>
```