# How to remove ALL stop words from text?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to using this JavaScript code:

```
var aStopWords = new Array ("a", "the", "blah"...);

(code to make it run, full code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/j2kbpdjr/)

// sText is the body of text that the keywords are being extracted from. 
// It's being separated into an array of words.

// remove stop words
for (var m = 0; m < aStopWords.length; m++) {
    sText = sText.replace(' ' + aStopWords[m] + ' ', ' ');
}
```

to get the keywords from a body of text. It works quite well, however, the issue I'm having is that it only seems to iterate through and ignore one instance of the words in the array `aStopWords`.

So if I have the following body of text:

`how are you today? Are you well?`

And I put `var aStopWords = new Array("are","well")` then it seems it will ignore the first instance of `are`, but still show the second `are` as a keyword. Whereas it will completely remove / ignore `well` from the keywords.

If anyone can help ignore all instances of the words in `aStopWords` from the keywords, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is your goal to remove every occurence of a list of words from a text?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Apologies. I have updated the question.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Yeah, that's right

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493028/javascript-replace-more-than-one-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this like this.

First, it splits the text into keywords. Then, it goes through all the keywords. While going through, it checks if it is a stopword. If so, it will be ignored. If not, the occurrence number of this keyword in the `result` object will be increased.

Then, the keywords are in a JavaScript object in the following form:

```
{ "this": 1, "that": 2 }
```

Objects are not sortable in JavaScript, but Arrays are. So, a remapping to the following structure is necessary:

```
[
    { "keyword": "this", "counter": 1 },
    { "keyword": "that", "counter": 2 }
]
```

Then, the array can be sorted by using the `counter` attribute. With the `slice()` function, only the top X values can be extracted from the sorted list.

```js
var stopwords = ["about", "all", "alone", "also", "am", "and", "as", "at", "because", "before", "beside", "besides", "between", "but", "by", "etc", "for", "i", "of", "on", "other", "others", "so", "than", "that", "though", "to", "too", "trough", "until"];
var text = document.getElementById("main").innerHTML;

var keywords = text.split(/[\s\.;:"]+/);
var keywordsAndCounter = {};
for(var i=0; i<keywords.length; i++) {
  var keyword = keywords[i];
  
  // keyword is not a stopword and not empty
  if(stopwords.indexOf(keyword.toLowerCase()) === -1 && keyword !== "") {
    if(!keywordsAndCounter[keyword]) {
      keywordsAndCounter[keyword] = 0;
    }
    keywordsAndCounter[keyword]++;
  }
}

// remap from { keyword: counter, keyword2: counter2, ... } to [{ "keyword": keyword, "counter": counter }, {...} ] to make it sortable
var result = [];
var nonStopKeywords = Object.keys(keywordsAndCounter);
for(var i=0; i<nonStopKeywords.length; i++) {
  var keyword = nonStopKeywords[i];
  result.push({ "keyword": keyword, "counter": keywordsAndCounter[keyword] });
}

// sort the values according to the number of the counter
result.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.counter - a.counter;
});

var topFive = result.slice(0, 5);
console.log(topFive);
```

```html
<div id="main">This is a test to show that it is all about being between others. I am there until 8 pm event though it will be late. Because it is "cold" outside even though it is besides me.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly for removing all instances of the stop words, there's one issue I'm having with this (sorry to be a pain). The issue is that this is listing ALL of the non-stop words, rather than only the top X number of reoccurring words.

Comment: @Jack, I've updated the answer with the following: The issue is, that an object cannot be sorted,  so you need to convert it from an object to an array (containing objects).