# Javascript replace all occurrences

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a sub-string of a string with a character in javascript.

I used following code to do that

```
av_text_to_display = av_text_to_display.replace("a*^!", "'");
```

but it can only replace first occurrence. I used following code for all occurrences

```
av_text_to_display = av_text_to_display.replace("a*^!", "'", "g");
```

but it is not a standard way. What is the standard way to do that?

Comment: What is not standard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Read the [docs for `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), and then please use regex instead of string literals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to replace that *literal* string, and not a regex matching that string, use an escaped regex:

```
av_text_to_display = av_text_to_display.replace(/a\*\^!/g, "'");
```

```js
var av_text_to_display = "here: a*^!, there: a*^! and also here, twice: a*^!a*^!";

av_text_to_display = av_text_to_display.replace(/a\*\^!/g, "'");

console.log(av_text_to_display);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching with a string instead of a RegExp, it should probably be:

```
av_text_to_display.replace(/a*\^!/g, "'");
```

Comment: Of course, that regex will never find any `a`s before the start of the string…

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex you can use the both `split` and `join` functions to do this :

```
your_string.split("a").join("'");
```

Hope this helps.