# How do I remove &#39; from a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

I have a String :

```
"Name : Cool Dude&#39;s Hat"
```

When I am trying to submit it to a forum it errors, when I take out the `&#39;` part it works fine. How would I write Javascript code that removes it?

Comment: You just want to remove the `&#39;`? Then you might look into using [`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). But it sounds like the problem is deeper than that.

Comment: I tried that @ MikeC, it doesnt replace it

Comment: It certainly does. `'hello&#39;world'.replace('&#39;', ' ')` produces `hello world`.

Comment: Where is error and what is specific error? Sounds like not escaping data before trying to do a db insert

Comment: honestly it doesnt work. My whole string is too big to post here. even when i try string.replace('&#39;', '') it still has the same characters

Comment: If you have multiple instances of it, you need to replace it with a regular expression and a global flag. `myStr.replace(/&#39;/g, '')`

Comment: As @MikeC pointed out, a regular expression is the way to go for replacing all occurences of a search string in another string. Also, are you aware, that `string.replace()` in JavaScript doesn't operate on the string itself, but returns a new string in which the occurences of the search string have been replaced?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: If "honestly it doesn't work" please edit the post with the code you tried. Note the `replace` method of a string returns a new string - it does not update the content of an existing string. You might also wish to revisit the necessity of using an HTML character escape sequence for a single quote character.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions and try to match the the parts of string that follow the same pattern and then append a replace function in the js expression if it matches any part.