# How to break to a new line when string contains "↵"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a string like this `var text = "aaaaaaa↵bbbbbb↵cccccc"` from the php server, and I want to output this string to the screen.

When there is a "↵", the following text goes to a new line. I am using AngularJS.

How can I achieve this by using plain Javascript or through AngularJS?

Comment: change all ↵ to `<br/>` perhaps?

Comment: `str = str.replace(\u21B5/g,'<br />');`

Comment: @GeorgeStocker you are misising a `/` at beginning of `\u21B5/g`

Comment: style="
    white-space: pre-wrap;
"
you can use css for wrapping

Answer (score 6):

Try to use replace function. It's pure javascript.

```
text.replace(/\u21B5/g,'<br/>')
```

`21B5` is the unicode for `↵`

Comment: None of these solutions work for me... Its like the `↵` does not exist so it cant be replaced. I can only see it on the browser console.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do that by doing a regex:

```
var text = "aaaaaaa↵bbbbbb↵cccccc";

text.replace(/↵/, '<br/>');

this will only replace the first one, by adding the g (global) parameter we will replace any occurence of this symbol, we simply put the g after the / like so 
text.replace(/↵/g, '<br/>');
```

Basically here we store the data in a variable called **text** then we use the string/regex method called replace on it **.replace()** that takes two parameters: the pattern to search and with what we are going to replace it;

Comment: this remplaces only the first occurrence.

Comment: Yeah my bad, you must add the g parameters which stands for global and that will search for any occurence and then replace it: text.replace(/↵/g, '<br/>');

Answer (score 2):

```
var newString = mystring.replace(/↵/g, "<br/>");
alert(newString);
```

You can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string).

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split([separator[, limit]])` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

```
var text = "aaaaaaa↵bbbbbb↵cccccc";
for(var i=0;i<text.split('↵').length;i++){
    // use text[i] to print the text the way you want
    // separated by <br>, create a new div element, whatever you want
    console.log(text[i]); 
}
```