# Replacing all instances of certain character in JS?

Tags: javascript, iteration

I am trying to create a simple function that replaces all instances of a certain character in a string in JS. In this instance, I want to replace all `a`'s with `o`'s.

I am pretty sure the code is right, but the output is still the original string.

```
function replaceLetter(string){
  for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++){
    if(string[i] == 'a'){
      console.log(string[i]);
      string[i] = 'o'
    }
  }
  return string;
}

replaceLetter('hahaha') // returns 'hahaha'
```

Why isn't it replacing a's with o's?

Comment: Strings are immutable -> [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Is this an algorithm design exercise, or is the goal actually to do sub-string replacement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like this:

```js
function replaceLetter(str) {
    return str.replace(/a/g, 'o');
}

var st = replaceLetter('hahaha');

console.log(st);
```

Or use another string to accumulate the result like this:

```js
function replaceLetter(str) {
    var res = '';                               // the accumulator (because string litterals are immutable). It should be initialized to empty string
  
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var c = str.charAt(i);                  // get the current character c at index i
        if(c == 'a') res += 'o';                // if the character is 'a' then replace it in res with 'o'
        else res += c;                          // otherwise (if it is not 'a') leave c as it is
    }

    return res;
}

var st = replaceLetter('hahaha');

console.log(st);
```

Answer (score 2):

I always like using `split()` and `join()`

```
var string = "assassination";
var newString = string.split("a").join("o");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Strings in Javascript are immutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type), and thus any changes to them aren't going to be reflected as you might expect.

Consider just using the [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function instead:

```
function replaceLetter(string){
  // This uses a regular expression to replace all 'a' characters with 'o'
  // characters (the /g flag indicates that all should be matched)
  return string.replace(/a/g,'o');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use a `for` loop:

```
function replaceLetter(string){
  var result = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    result += string[i] === 'a' ? 'o' : string[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

You have to build a new string like this, because as mentioned in a comment, strings are immutable. You can write `string[4] = 'b'` and it won't cause an error, but it won't do anything either.

It's probably overkill, but you could use `reduce`, which does the looping internally and maintains the `result` variable:

```
const replaceLetter = string => 
  [...string].reduce((result, chr) => 
    result += (chr === 'a' ? 'o' : chr), '');
```

However, for this particular case, the regexp solution shown in other answers is probably preferable.