# Using jQuery I need to replace spaces inside href with hyphens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of links that direct to a page which corresponds to each of the 50 states in the US.

I am looping through each states in an array and adding it the href for each but for states that contain two words I need to replaces the space (`' '`) between them with a hyphen(`'-'`).

example: `New York` must be replaced with `New-York`.

`<a href="http://www.projectknow.com/find/New York/" class="spaces">`

MUST BE REPLACED WITH

`<a href="http://www.projectknow.com/find/New-York/" class="spaces">`

This is what I got so far but it does NOT work. Still new to jQuery and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var option = '';
for (var i = 0; i < states.length;i++){
    option += '<li><a href="http://www.states.com/find/'+ states[i] +'/" 
    class="spaces">'+ states[i] +'</a></li>';
}

$('.menu').append(option);

$("a.spaces").each(function (){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr("href").replace("","-"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your string does not contain a space.  Furthermore, in JS, replace doesn't replace all instances of the search string unless the search argument is a regular expression, you'll need to implement something like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116614

Comment: Why change the states[i] after the fact?  Why not change it as you build the links?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code instead:

```
$(this).attr('href', $(this).attr("href").replace(/\s/g, "-");
```

Comment: Why not do this replace as you are building the links, not after the fact?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can replace it before add it to a link tag then you don't need to handle it after added, like this way:

```js
var option = '';
for (var i = 0; i < states.length;i++){
   var state = states[i].replace(/ /g, '-');
   option += '<li><a href="http://www.states.com/find/'+ state +'/" class="spaces">'+ states[i] +'</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var states = [ 'New York', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico' ];

$('.menu').append(states.map(function(state){
  return '<li><a href="http://www.states.com/find/'+ state.replace(/[ ]/g, '-') +'/" class="spaces">'+ state +'</a></li>';
}).join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're so close!

Problem:

`$(this).attr('href', $(this).attr("href").replace("","-"));`

because `"" != " "`

Answer:

`$(this).attr('href', $(this).attr("href").replace(" ","-"));`

but replace only replaces the first occurrence. We could suggest regex, but as you stated you're still trying to figure things out; regex would just confuse you at this time

```
function replaceAll(str, find, replace) { 
  str = str.replace(find, replace);
  if(str.indexOf(find) > -1) { 
    return replaceAll(str, find, replace);
  } 
  return str;
}
```

and then `$(this).attr('href', replaceAll($(this).attr('href'), ' ', '+'));`

Comment: Not quite.  [string.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) used this way only replaces the first instance.  What if there are more than one space?