# Replace all sub-strings in a string not just first sub-string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to replace all instances of a sub-string in a string

I am using

```
A1.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with)
```

But it is only replacing the first instance

Ex

```
to_replace = ",@"
replace_with = "|"
```

I get for a cell value

```
a,@b,@c,@d  >>  a|b,@c,@d
```

I need

```
a,@b,@c,@d >> a|b|c|d
```

I can not figure out if their is a setting to replace all not just the first instance

Thanks

Comment: Put it in a loop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string

Comment: You can use regular expression. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: `A1.toString().replace(RegExp(to_replace,"g"),replace_with)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this trick to do it:

```
A1.toString().split(to_replace).join(replace_with)
```

this will divide your string to an array without substring to replace, and then will build it again to a new string with the new substring, acting like a replace all function

Comment: Wonderful. thanks regev