# remove or \r in JavaScript or C#

Tags: javascript, c#

How can I remove or replace  \r in javascript text or in backend code in C#
I have a variable in javascript like this:

```
var text="name\rhi\r"
```

> \r means line break or next line

I try to this approach to replace:

```
text=text.replace("\r",",");
```

but does not work

Comment: Are you sure `var text=name\r\hi\r\ ` is not throwing errors at you?

Comment: `\r means line break or next line`. No, it means `carriage return`. Line break/new line/line feed is `\n`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string

Comment: Yes I am sure @Federico klez Culloca

Comment: @AliBesharatinia Are you really sure? Maybe check again, because `var text=name\r\hi\r\ ` isn't a valid expression.

Comment: @Herohtar  really? I don't sure

Comment: Really. If you intend it to be a string you need quotes, for example: `var text="name\r\hi\r\"`, except that isn't valid either because the slashes act as escape characters. Maybe you want the string to look like `var text="name\rhi\r"`?

Comment: @Herohtar yes that is corecct : var text="name\rhi\r"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# Replace will work:

```
        string source = "\rhi\ryou";
        string result = source.Replace("\r", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically in JS, using replace("/r",",") only replaces the first thing it finds, try using replace(/\/r/g,",")