# How can i replace %20 to + with javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a question. 
In this code i use +tag to set a search words when user speak in microphone.

```
var searching = function(tag) {
            var string = "Procurando "+tag;
            var str = string.split("");
            var el = document.getElementById('liya');
            (function animate() {
                str.length > 0 ? el.innerHTML += str.shift() : clearTimeout(running); 
                var running = setTimeout(animate, 30);
            })();

            setTimeout(function () {
                $(location).attr('href', 'https://yazui.co/liya/search.php?q='+tag)
            }, 3000);            
        };
```

It's ok! But in results, url showing with %20 when have many words

```
search.php?q=words%20words%20words
```

How can i change %20 to + in this code?

I need that url returns

```
search.php?q=words+words+words
```

Comment: You URL is being [encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), you just need to decode it. FYI `%20` is a space character and not a `+`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string `tag.replace(/ /g,'+')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: Why do you need to do this replacement? Both `%20` and `+` will be decoded to space.

Comment: because my search understand word+word+word and not understand word%20word%20

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
var searching = function(tag) {
            var string = "Procurando "+tag;
            var str = string.split("");
            var el = document.getElementById('liya');
            (function animate() {
                str.length > 0 ? el.innerHTML += str.shift() : clearTimeout(running); 
                var running = setTimeout(animate, 30);
            })();

            setTimeout(function () {
                $(location).attr('href', 'https://yazui.co/liya/search.php?q='+tag.replace(/%20/g, "+");)
            }, 3000);            
        };
```