# Adding a "+" to a " " in node.js for a movie api

Tags: node.js, ajax

I know this will be a simple question. I am new coding and still have a lot to learn. I am running a movie API with node. As you know API's searches cannot have spaces `" "` and need a plus sign `"+"` in order to search a string. Example when I search Die Hard on the terminal it comes back as a movie called Die and does not recognize "Hard". If I search it as Die+Hard I will get the movie I am looking for. How do I add that plus sign without having the user write the plus sign in the search? Thank you for your help.

```
var axios = require("axios");

movieName = (process.argv[2]);


var queryUrl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + movieName + "&y=&plot=short&apikey=...";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

To replace all instances of a space in a string (let's call it `str`) with `+`:

```
str.replace(/ /g, "+");
```

To replace all instances of any whitespace characters with a `+`:

```
str.replace(/\s/g, "+");
```

For more information, see the [MDN docs on `String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: That was my first guess with it but it did not work.

Comment: Ahem. `console.log('hey look at these spaces turned into + instead'.replace(/ /g, '+'));`

Answer (score 0):

var movieName = process.argv.slice(2).join("+");

this took care of it. Thank you for the help.