# how to get a string between to identical string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this string

```
var behavior = "[&quot;Automático&quot;, &quot;Manual&quot;, &quot;Automático&quot;]"
```

And i would like to get the same behavior variable but with something like that:

```
var behavior = "[Automático, Manual, Automático]"
```

using regex or other solution if it works.! Thaks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: You mean `var behavior = ["Automáticot", "Manual", "Automático"]` right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: Do you want a *string* or an actual array in the end? And if it's a string, do you want `Automático&quot`?

Comment: I want the same string but with the format "[Automático, Manual, Automático]", keeping on mind that the variable I'm working on is a string, and not an array and I want the same variable but with the aforementioned format. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for JSON.parse

```js
var behavior = "[&quot;Automático&quot;, &quot;Manual&quot;, &quot;Automático&quot;]"
console.log(
  JSON.parse(behavior.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'))
)
```

Comment: this is a solution but I want in a string variable wich is the same that I'm on wornking on.

Comment: So don’t use JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

The solutions Thaks to mplungjan.

```
var behavior = "[&quot;Automático&quot;, &quot;Manual&quot;, &quot;Automático&quot;]";
behavior = behavior.replace(/&quot;/g,'"');
console.log(behavior)
```