# How to convert Node.js path __dirname for on my own form?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm setting up a new server, and want to save arbitrary file in my project directory. So I use Node.js `path`, `__dirname`.

I want to convert `__dirname`, now my `__dirname` is `d:\algorithm-visualizer\`
but I want to `__dirname` is `d:\\\algorithm-visualizer\\\` form (have two double-escaping the backslashes).
How can I convert this form?

Comment: Why don't you just search for the `\ ` characters and replace them by `\\\\`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)