# How to replace using regex?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, replace

```
var result = [{"figure figure watch?v="}, {"figure data watch?v="}]
console.log(result.replace(res=> res.('figure', 'ifigure', 'watch?v=' , 'embeded/')))
```

I want result = [{"ifigure ifigure embeded/"}, {"ifigure data  embeded/"}]

Can you help?

Comment: You can use replace of JavaScript like str.replace("figure figure watch?v=", "ifigure ifigure embeded/");

Comment: yea, but the data will be fetched form database. So I am not sure always figure will be availabe so I need if availabe then replace all figure to ifigure and watch?v= to embeded/

Comment: `[{"figure figure watch?v="}, {"figure data watch?v="}]` gives a syntax error. What actual input do you have? Is it `[ "figure figure watch?v=", "figure data watch?v=" ]` ?

Comment: Yes [ "figure figure watch?v=", "figure data watch?v=" ] this

Comment: You need to check if data is available like if(res){ //do here logic}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way will be to use Array.map method with regex -

```
var result = ["figure figure watch?v=", "figure data watch?v="];
result.map(e => e.replace(/watch\?v=/g, "embeded/").replace(/figure/g, "ifigure"));
// (2) ["ifigure ifigure embeded/", "ifigure data embeded/"]
```

Check out this question for more on replacing with Regex [Fastest method to replace all instances of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558)

Answer (score 1):

First of all  [{"ifigure ifigure embeded/"}, {"ifigure data embeded/"}] you have a syntax error here. you cannot enclose string in an object. you will need to do something like this. if in future you want to replace new string, just add them in this object.

```
var mapObj = {
   'watch?v=':"embeded/",
   'figure':"ifigure"
};

var result = ["figure figure watch?v=", "figure data watch?v="];
console.log(result.map(res=> res.replace(/watch\?v=|figure/gi, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
})));
```