# .trim() for other characters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, trim

Is there any function that can do .trim for specified characters or string?

Something like:

```
var x = '@@@hello world@@';
console.log(x.trim('@')); // prints 'hello world'

var y = 'hellohellohelloworld';
console.log(y.trim('hello')); // prints ' world'

var z = '@@hello@world@@';
console log(z.trim('@')); // prints 'hello@world'
```

Even tho I can do without this, it would be way less efficient and not as clean

Comment: How about the replace function?
Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116558/fastest-method-to-replace-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string/2116614

Comment: Maybe `.replace(/^[@]+/g,"").replace(/[@]+$/g,"")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68808864/3001761?

Comment: Yes, is there a simple function that can do the job?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pattern with an alternation `|` to match either what you want to remove at the start or at the end of the string by repeating it 1 or more time in a non capture group.

The repetition looks like this `(?:@)+` for a single @ char, or like this `(?:hello)+` for the word hello

If you want to make a function for it and want to pass any string, you have to escape the regex meta characters with a `\`

```js
var x = '@@@hello world@@';
var y = 'hellohellohelloworld';
var z = '@@hello@world@@';
var a = '*+hello*+'

const customTrim = (strSource, strToRemove) => {
  let escaped = strToRemove.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
  return strSource.replace(new RegExp(`^(?:${escaped})+|(?:${escaped})+$`, 'g'), "")
};

console.log(customTrim(x, "\\s"));
console.log(customTrim(y, "hello"));
console.log(customTrim(z, "@"));
console.log(customTrim(a, "*+"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export function trim(str: string, char: string): string {
  const leading = new RegExp(`^[${char}]+`);
  const trailing = new RegExp(`[${char}]+$`);
  return str.replace(leading, "").replace(trailing, "");
}
```

Comment: You'll need to escape the passed `char` to reliably create RegExp. see: [Regular Expressions: Escaping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping)